# Batch program: How to redirect commands and do conditional statements

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I'm trying to create batch file to upload files to S3 to run as scheduled task. So I want some conditional statements for logging and error notification.

My problem is how can I run a command_A that it's stderr and stdout are appended to a file,
then if command_A ran successfully, run command_B logging the time and success message to that same file,
but if command_A failed, then run command_C notifying that the scheduled task failed logging the time and fail message to the same file.

I tried something like this:

```
aws sync "directory" MyS3Bucket >> "folder_directory/log.log" 2>&1
&& echo Successfully synced on %date%-%time%: >> "folder_directory/log.log"
|| echo Synchronization failed on %date%-%time%: >> "folder_directory/log.log"
```

This will successfully execute the first line, but then return "&& was unexpected at this time." to the CMD and does not get logged (because I'm only appending stdout I'm assuming).

and I tried

```
if aws sync "directory" MyS3Bucket >> "folder_directory/log.log" 2>&1 ; then
(
    echo Successfully synced on %date%-%time%: >> "folder_directory/log.log"
) else (
    echo Synchronization failed on %date%-%time%: >> "folder_directory/log.log"
)
fi
```

And this just doesn't work at all.
How can I achieve appending outputs and conditional statements for both success and fail?

Comment: Thats because your three lines should be on one line. Alternatively use these three lines instead, `aws sync "directory" MyS3Bucket >> "folder_directory/log.log" 2>&1 && (`, `echo Successfully synced on %date%-%time%: >> "folder_directory/log.log") || (`, and `echo Synchronization failed on %date%-%time%: >> "folder_directory/log.log")`.

Comment: I suppose you could shorten that to these three lines too: `(aws sync "directory" MyS3Bucket && (`, `echo Successfully synced on %date%-%time%:) || (`, and `echo Synchronization failed on %date%-%time%:) >> "folder_directory\log.log" 2>>&1)`.